# How do I have an option to save the progress in C and resume next time I execute the program?

Tags: c

I have a question. I have to write a code ( C language ) for a project for school, in which I have the option to add a function (for extra credit)  that let's the user save the progress of the application and resume it later whenever he feels like it, the thing is I have no idea how to do that and I haven't found a way yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: since it's a project for school, you're unlikely to get a full solution. to give a hint, though, it'd help to know what the program actually is.

Comment: Run it in a VM, then pause/resume the VM!

Comment: It would be useful to know what the program is doing...

Comment: Yeah I wasn't look for a solution, just a way on how to make it, such as, you have to use this and then I would find my way from there. I'm supposed to make a game, Reversi or Othello.

Comment: How about saving the board situation to a text file, and give the user an option to load that file?

Comment: That might work, thanks. Will give it a try and see how I do :)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to store your state in a `struct`, for example if you're writing a chess or checkers game:

```
struct game_state {
    char board[8][8];
    int turn;
};
```

Then you can simply use `write()` or `fwrite()` to save this struct to a file, and `read()` or `fread()` to load it back again later.

You could write the state as text instead, but that will probably take a bit more effort.

Answer (score -1):

The important point when storing the application's state (for a game like Othello) is to make the stored file inspectable and editable, so that you can use any text editor to compose puzzles or game situations.

Such a file might look like this:

```
--------
--------
--------
---ox---
---xo---
--------
--------
--------
x to play
```

This would be the simplest file format. In addition to the board position you have to store whose turn it is, since players don't always move alternately.

Comment: This completely misses the point of the question, and isn't even true in general. A binary save format is perfectly fine for many applications. But the point of the question is how to do it at all.